# Magento 1.7 - remove index.php from url

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the following settings:

`Use Web Server Rewrites => Yes`

In `htaccess`  I have `RewriteBase /`

Caching is disabled.

In one of my email templates I use `<a href='{{store url="doc/toc.pdf"}}'>xxxx</a>`

This results in `/index.php/doc/toc.pdf/`

How do I remove the `/index.php`  part?

The links in the rest of the store do not show `index.php` in the url.

I also have this when using `Mage:getUrl` in a `.phtml` file

Comment: Have you tried `../doc` and `/doc`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this solution somewhere which works for me:

`Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);`

this returns:

`http://mydomain.com/`  so `index.php` is removed from the url.

And in a template I now use this:

`{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}doc/toc.pdf`

which also returns the url without index.php

Comment: Is it recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Remember to clear your cache.